# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, eris-discord

I'm setting up localisation with rethinkdb and using the Eris discord library but I keep getting following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

I have added `msg` so I can be able to do `msg.author.id` and it still wouldn't fix my issue.

```
function t (msg, context, object = { locale: 'en' }, values = {}) {
    let userLocale;
    if (object.ownerID) {
        userLocale = this.r.table('locales').get(msg.author.id);
    }
    let string = (locales[userLocale] || (locales[object.locale] || locales['en']));

    process.send({ name: 'log', msg: msg.author.id }); // Error

    let processing = 'Translation for this command has not been found, please report it to Support!';
    if (string) {
        processing = string;
        for (let part of context.split('.')) {
            processing = processing[part];
        }
    }

    let placeholders = processing.match(/{{[^{}]+}}/g);
    for (let hold in placeholders) {
        let str = placeholders[hold];
        processing = processing.replace(str, values[str.replace('{{', '').replace('}}', '')]);
    }

    return processing;
}

global.t = t;
module.exports = { loadLocales, t };
```

I expected it to print `153286414212005888` (My Discord ID) but just errors that and print undefined.

Comment: What is `msg.author`?

Comment: Who is calling this method and what is passed as the msg object? I would check that before trying to access it.

Comment: @JackBashford it is the author of who ran the command.

Comment: No, but log it and see what's in it. What does `console.log(msg.author)` show?

Comment: @tomerpacific i'm calling this method by using a simple command I made called `testcmd`. I don't understand by 'what is passed as the msg object'.

Comment: @JackBashford it logged `undefined` and also errored `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` 

```javascript
if (string) {
        processing = string;
        for (let part of context.split('.')) {
            processing = processing[part];
        }
    }

Comment: @ETLegacy, if you are calling this method, you have to pass in parameters. What are you passing in?

Comment: @tomerpacific I'm passing in `msg` and to make it return the ID of the person who used it which is me

Comment: @ETLegacy, as I asked previously, what is the ```msg```? Can you show what it contains, it's format?

Comment: @tomerpacific `msg` can do a lot of different things from being used getting discord members to servers. `msg` in this case is supposed to get the user who ran the command. It is also a built in thing on the [Eris](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/Message) discord library and it definitely has an author object.

Comment: @ETLegacy, based on the log messages you posted, msg is undefined. Meaning there is nothing there. Since I do not understand the logic behind the code snippet you posted, it would be wise to understand what gets passed in. When you log msg, what is there? Can you show the line executing the t function?

Comment: @tomerpacific it logged

[19:03:28] Cluster 1 | errors.noManageServer 
[19:03:28] Cluster 1 | TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at t (C:\Users\etleg\Desktop\TrinitySharder\src\utils\locales.js:33:34)
    at Trinity.testcmdCommand (C:\Users\etleg\Desktop\TrinitySharder\src\commands\Utilities\testcmd.js:2:31)
    at Trinity.exports.handle (C:\Users\etleg\Desktop\TrinitySharder\src\events\messageCreate.js:51:45)

Comment: @tomerpacific, take a look at this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/yLGCGLM.png), the problem with `msg` at this point that it sees it as `errors.noManageServer`. But that isn't what i'm trying to do

Comment: @ETLegacy, I think the error in the screenshot is a tall tale sign of your problem. It seems like you are missing some sort of permission.

Comment: @tomerpacifi, you are definitely lost haha. That is my localisation system just like this [one](https://github.com/minemidnight/oxyl/tree/master/locales) that will show you what i'm trying to do (it is not my code, but something like it).

Comment: @ETLegacy I'm actively using eris for bot dev rn lol. Can you edit your post to include the snippet of where the `t` function is being called? Make sure that the Message object is being parsed first before anything else!

Comment: @RekkisomoHarley Edited.

Comment: @ETLegacy That doesn't answer my question. What are you doing when you do `t()`? What are you putting in the `()`?

Comment: @RekkisomoHarley I do for example `msg.channel.createMessage(t('errors.noManageServer'))` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @ETLegacy you need to parse your `msg` into the function as well. Like so `t(msg, 'errors.noManageServer')`. If you want to use variables inside the `t` function, you would obviously need to parse them to the function as well (in order) :)

Comment: @RekkisomoHarley that isn't my issue here. My issue is that in my locales handler, i'm trying to get message author so i can be able to fetch people's locales. You can see on the code above i done `userLocale = this.r.table('locales').get(msg.author.id);`. Basically, `msg.author.id` doesn't work as i wanted it.